# Why are these commas correct?

Tags: commas

Reading and observing varies things daily, I noticed that these types of commas are correct, but why? Why are these commas used here:

> "I want to meet with you on Sunday, tomorrow."
>
> "I like to help communities, with an emphasis on supporting schools.
>
> "It was a nice day today, on Memorial Day."

Why do these commas make sense, and why do they belong where they belong?

Comment: How would the meaning change if the second sentence didn't have the comma?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but highly-experienced English writers always put the comma there. Why?

Comment: The commas are hardly the problem with the above.

Comment: Sunday and tomorrow are in apposition. They are one and the same. Nouns or noun phrases in apposition are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

These are non-essential phrases/clauses. According to OWL by Purdue, these non-essential parts need to be separated from the other parts of the sentence.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/